# Question about Lipschitz conditions

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Let $f$ be a function on some real interval $[a,b]$. Suppose that $\forall x\in [a,b]$, there exists a positive constant $C$ such that
$$ |f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y| $$
for all $y \in [a,b]$.

Does each $x \in [a,b]$ have a neighborhood $U$ such that

$$ |f(t)-f(s)| \leq C'|t-s| $$

for some $C' > 0$ and $\forall s,t \in U$?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to nail down the various uses of quantifiers here. In your first inequality, is C allowed to depend on x, or on y, or on both?

Comment: @YemonChoi I edited the question to express what I think is the intended meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(t) = t\sin(1/t)$ on $[0,1]$.